# Java: My statements int he Main method are printing, but not in my other methods

Tags: java, methods, input, output, println

So here's the code. It's the skeleton for a calendar program, that looks up a month and year. I'm not sure why our teacher wanted the command line arguments bit, so ignore that for now, unless it's impacting my code. At the bottom of the page, I will display the output. When I receive an output, nothing from the second method, (which deals with months,) will display, despite having called for user input in that method. I would like my program to first ask what year the user is wanting to look at, and then the month. I'm sure I'm making some obvious mistake, but could someone point me in the correct direction?

```
package calendardisplay;

/**
*
* @author TheDancingPope
*/
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalendarDisplay 

{
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);    

    public static final String MONTH_NAME[] = {"","Jan","Feb","Mar", 
                                               "Apr", "May","June", 
                                                "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", 
                                                "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
    public static void outputMonthName(int month)
    {
    System.out.println(MONTH_NAME[month]);
    }

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

        for (int i = 1; i < MONTH_NAME.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Month number:" + i + 
                "\nis Month Name:\n" + MONTH_NAME[i]);
        }





        //Processes command line argument
        System.out.println("Number of command line arguments: " + args.length);

        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Argument " + i + ": " + args[i]);
        }
    //This next section handles the leap year scanner. Based on the 
    //calculation below, paired with the user input, I will be able to tell
    //whether or not they picked a leap year.

    System.out.println("Please choose a year");
    int yearChosen = scan.nextInt();

    boolean isLeapYear = ((yearChosen % 4 == 0) && (yearChosen % 100 !=0)
            || (yearChosen % 400 == 0));
    System.out.println("You chose\n" + yearChosen);
        if (isLeapYear)
        {
            System.out.println (yearChosen + "\n is a leap year.");
        } else
        System.out.println(yearChosen + "\n is not a leap year.");

}
//This is where the months are processed. In here, I will sort through
//the months chosen via the user, and based on their month, I will bring up
//a formatted calendar for that month, with the correct amount of days in it.
public static int monthTime()
{
    System.out.println("Please chose a month:\n");
    int monthChosen = scan.nextInt();
    String monthString;
    switch (monthChosen)
        {
        case 1:  monthString = "January";
                 break;
        case 2:  monthString = "February";
                 break;
        case 3:  monthString = "March";
                 break;
        case 4:  monthString = "April";
                 break;
        case 5:  monthString = "May";
                 break;
        case 6:  monthString = "June";
                 break;
        case 7:  monthString = "July";
                 break;
        case 8:  monthString = "August";
                 break;
        case 9:  monthString = "September";
                 break;
        case 10: monthString = "October";
                 break;
        case 11: monthString = "November";
                 break;
        case 12: monthString = "December";
                 break;
        default: monthString = "Invalid month";

        break;
        }
    System.out.println("You chose:\n" + monthString);
    return monthChosen;
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get the following output in my little netbeans box below my code:

```
run:
Month number:1
is Month Name:
Jan
Month number:2
is Month Name:
Feb
Month number:3
is Month Name:
Mar
Month number:4
is Month Name:
Apr
Month number:5
is Month Name:
May
Month number:6
is Month Name:
June
Month number:7
is Month Name:
Jul
Month number:8
is Month Name:
Aug
Month number:9
is Month Name:
Sep
Month number:10
is Month Name:
Oct
Month number:11
is Month Name:
Nov
Month number:12
is Month Name:
Dec
Number of command line arguments: 0
Please choose a year
2015
You chose
2015
2015
is not a leap year.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)
```

It gave me a prompt as the user to enter in a year, but not a month. I've prompted the program to initialize an int scanner in that method, but I get nothing. What am I doing wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only method run by default is the Main method. To call the other methods, you have to include a call to them inside your Main method.

Answer (score 2):

Your `monthTime()` method is never called. You probably want to call it at the end of your `main` method.

Answer (score 1):

You have not called the function monthTime() in your main, try calling it after your yearChosen?